Are the proposed truth tables for the rules correct?
I'm trying to propose truth tables for the following two rules which are originally defined on page 5 in this paper:
Strict rule is of the form $\phi_1,......, \phi_n \rightarrow \phi$, informally meaning that if $ \phi_1,.....,\phi_n$ hold, then without exception it holds that $\phi$.
Defeasible rule is of the form $\phi_1,......, \phi_n \Rightarrow \phi$, informally meaning that if $ \phi_1,.....,\phi_n$ hold, then it presumably holds that $\phi$.
Now, if A is the antecedent and B is the consequent, are the truth tables for the strict and defeasible rules, shared below, valid?
      Strict Defeasible
A  B  A->B   A=>B
T  T  T      T
T  F  N/A    T (presumably holds)
F  T  T      T 
F  F  T      T 

If they are not correct, kindly rectify them with explanations.

Long comment
It seems to me that the "Stict rule" is simply Logical consequence: there is no situation when the premises all hold and the conclusion does not.
If so, the truth table must match that for the conditional, with False in the second row, instead of N/A.
Obviously, the details will be defined by the semantics: is it bivalent? are there three truth-values? are there truth-value gaps?
Regarding the "Defeasible rule", the tabular representation does not add much if we have no way to assess what "presumably holds" mean.

There's not much information available in the literature except the source I mentioned in the question.
In case of strict rules, in the second row, it is equivalent to an open circuit.
In case of defeasible rules, IMO "presumably holds" means if the antecedent is true, the consequence may or may not be true - both are allowed. So, both the first and second rows are marked true.
Unfortunately, not much information about these two rules is available. What do you think?

@Debbie - but in the case ⇒ if you mark all four case as T this gives us no information at all: every combination of premises+conclusion will satisfies the rule, and this is not what we expect.

I agree with you on the part of defeasible rule.
